# search and edit function no copy paste?

Tags: c, function, search, struct

Hi this code is just an example of what im working on. I've got the solution by copying everything from my search function and dump it into my edit function. Is there any better solution rather than just copy pasting?

```
 struct inventory
    {
        float a,b,c,d;
        char something[MAXSIZE];
    };
typedef struct inventory Inventory;
```

struct will contain some float integer and some characters.

```
void search(const Inventory inv[], int np); // declare search function
void edit(struct inventory inventoryRegister[],int np);

int main(void)
    {

        int np=0;
        struct inventory inventoryRegister[MAXSIZE];


// calling the functions search and edit

            search(inventoryRegister, np);
            edit(inventoryRegister, np);

        return 0;
        }

void search(const Inventory inv[], int np)
{
     int i, 
     float min, max;

     printf("Enter min max");
     scanf("%f %f", &min, &max); 

     for (i = 0; i < np; i++)
        if (inv[i].a >= low && inv[i].a <= high)
             {
                     print..
                 }
    //repeat for b,c,d and something
    }

void edit(struct inventory inventoryRegister[],int np)
{
      int a;
      print("Enter new a");
          scanf("%f", &a);

    // Here i can copy and paste  my entire search function and do a loop to replace the min & max with my new input a. 
But is there any easier way to do it? say i call the search(); and somehow extract the elements between min & max and do a loop replacement with a? 
Any suggestion?


    }
```

Comment: Have a struct which stores valid locations of `min` and `max` say `struct loc { int miloc,int maxloc};` To get the locations of min and max, create a function which returns this `struct loc`, and then you can call this function to get the locations and search/print/edit values by iterating through the range of your array.Does that make sense?

Comment: @Recker i kind of get it but not 100% can make some simple sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer : Its a kind of a psuedo code

```
struct MinMaxLocation
{
    int minloc;
    int maxloc;
};

struct MinMaxLocation getMinMaxLocation(struct inventory inventoryRegister[],float min,float max)
{
    // your logic to find min and max locations here 

    struct MinMaxLocation loc;
    loc.minloc = // min element location
        loc.maxloc = // max element location
        return loc;
}

void search(....)
{
    struct MinMaxLocation loc_here_search = getMinMaxLocation(inventoryRegister,min,max);
    for (i = loc_search_here.min; i < loc_search_here.max; i++)
    {
        print ... 
    }
}

void edit(....)
{
    struct MinMaxLocation loc_here_search = getMinMaxLocation(inventoryRegister,min,max);
    for (i = loc_search_here.min; i < loc_search_here.max; i++)
    {
        edit the values here ... 
    }
}
```